# Class TrueOleDBGrid80.TDBGrid of control DBGrid1 was not a loaded control class

Tags: vb.net, dbgrid, tdbgrid

I have an existing vb project that uses True DBGrid. I opened the source file in a Win7 PC, and I installed True dbGrid 8.0 Pro. Now, the error comes out: Class TrueOleDBGrid80.TDBGrid of control DBGrid1 was not a loaded control class.

Is there any settings to solve this problem?

Thanks